# My bike won’t change out of first gear

Tags: maintenance, derailleur-rear

NoI’ve tried changing the looseness of the H and L screws but my great problem remains the same. It won’t change out of first gear even when I manually put it into another gear. The back derailer is quite close to the back chain but and won’t move across at all to allow it to go on a smaller change bit.

Comment: Does the derailleur move at all when you move the shifter? Is the shifter cable tight?

Comment: Can you add some photos ?   Generally the High and Low limit screws don't need changing - they stop the chain going off the sides of the cassette.   Try using your fingers to pull on any exposed section of inner cable, and the rear derailleur should move sideways toward the center of the bike.  Is the bike rusty/stored outside?  Has it ever worked to change gear?